# Laravel 4 multiple users security and authentication

Tags: laravel-4, authentication, multi-user

I am developing a multiple user web application. My concerns are about the security, I'm wondering if this is the secure way to put it together ?

I have done the following in `filters.php`, three new filters.

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::guest('login');
        }
    }
});

Route::filter('user', function(){
    if(Auth::guest()){
        return Redirect::route('login');
    }else{
        if(Auth::user()->role == 2){
            return Redirect::route('/users/users');
        }
    }
});

Route::filter('admin', function(){
    if(Auth::guest()){
        return Redirect::route('login');
    }else{
        if(Auth::user()->role == 1){
            return Redirect::route('/admin/admin');
        }
    }
});

Route::filter('business', function(){
    if(Auth::guest()){
        return Redirect::route('login');
    }else{
        if(Auth::user()->role == 1){
            return Redirect::route('/business/business');
        }
    }
});
```

In `routes.php` I have added the following :

```
    Route::group(array('before' => 'admin'), function(){

        Route::resource('user', 'UserController');

        Route::get('user/dashboard', array(
            'as' =>'user-dashboard',
            'uses' => 'UserController@show'
        ));

    // Route::group(array('before' => 'user'), function(){
        Route::get('admin/dashboard', array(
              'as' =>'admin-dashboard',
              'uses' => 'AdminController@getAdmin'
        ));

    // });

    Route::group(array('before' => 'business'), function(){
        Route::get('business/dashboard', array(
            'as' =>'business-dashboard',
            'uses' => 'BusinessController@getBusiness'
        ));
    });
```

In `AdminController.php` I have added the following :

```
public function show($id){
        $user = User::find($id);

        return View::make('admin.show')
        ->with('title', 'admin dashboard')
        ->with('user', $user);
    }
```

In the `admin/show.blade.php` file I have added the following :

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')
    @if(Auth::check())

        @if(Auth::user()->role==1)
        <div class="container">
            <h1>{{ $user->email }}</h1>
                @else
            <p> you are not signed in</p>
        @endif
    @else
        <?php return Redirect::route('login') ?>
    @endif
@stop
```

In `UserController.php` I have added the following :

```
public function show(){
        return View::make('users.index')
        ->with('title', 'dashboard');
    }
```

In `users/index.blade.php` I have added the following :

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')
    @if(Auth::check())
        @if(Auth::user()->role==2)
                ........... 
                @else 
        <div class="container">
            <h3>your are not signed in</h3>
        </div>
        @endif
    @else
        <?php return Redirect::route('login')->with('global', 'your not allowed here') ?>
    @endif
@stop
```

and the business role is done the same way.

In the view files for admin :

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')
    @if(Auth::check())
        @if(Auth::user()->role==1)
            <h2>welcome {{ Auth::user()->email }}, you are logged in as an administrator </h2>
        @else
            <p> you are not signed in</p>
        @endif
    @else
        <p><?php return Redirect::route('login')->with('global', 'your not allowed here') ?></p>
    @endif
@stop
```

And for users :

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')
    @if(Auth::check())
        @if(Auth::user()->role==2)
            <h2>welcome {{ Auth::user()->email }}, you are logged in as an user </h2>
        @else
            <p> you are not signed in</p>
        @endif
    @else
        <p><?php return Redirect::route('login')->with('global', 'your not allowed here') ?></p>
    @endif
@stop
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to check for `Auth::guest()` in each one of your filters, instead use your already existing `auth` filter in combination with the other filters, like this :

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth|admin'), function() {});
```

Or use this alternate array syntax :

```
Route::group(array('before' => array('auth', 'admin')), function() {});
```

I'm not sure if the commenting of the route group that's around the route for `admin/dashboard` is intentional, but with that commented there are no route filters for that route so keep that in mind, you probably need to uncomment that.

Also, no need to `Auth::check()` and `return Redirect::route('login')` in the view - authentication should be done in the controller or via a route filter, you shouldn't even render the view if the user isn't logged in.

Other than that, these parts of your code seem pretty secure, but don't blame me nor Stack Exchange if something goes wrong, if in doubt ask a professional.

Comment: Where you say `Route::group(array('before' => 'auth|admin'), function() {});` Then how can you distinguish what views are showed only to auth and what to only admin inside that route group?? Any example?

Comment: @pathros it's not about determining what view to show (that will be determined based on the route), it's just to require both of these route filters to match to return the view, and return "unauthorized" otherwise.

Comment: Then where else can i control access to views for each user type? I don't want admin to see the same pages as other users like business, normal_user, etc.

Comment: @pathros make separate route filters for each group, and require one of them for each route group.

Comment: All right. Got it now working properly by reading your advice and by reading this post [laravel roles de usuarios](http://uno-de-piera.com/sencillo-sistema-de-roles-de-usuarios-en-laravel-4/)